# How to do incremental load in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have DB tables where there are no identity column. We have client data fetched from DB2 to SQL Server and unfortunately DB2 design doesn't have identity columns.

Now we have some data inserted, updated and deleted from source (DB2/SQL Server) and these data I want to load to destination (SQL Server) using some incremental load concept.

I tried SSIS lookups in Dataflow task however it's taking huge time to simply insert one new record. Please note that, in "lookup transformation editor" I'm mapping all "available input columns" to available "available lookup columns " as there is no identity column. I think, this is why it's taking time. I have few tables having around 20 million records.

Is there any faster method /ways available to do this, specially when table does not have identity column? Is except or SQL merge will help?

I'm open to have any other approach other than SSIS.

Comment: Can you check my answer is my answer helpful to you??

Comment: Thanks. Will try and update.

Comment: Date column?  Is there any sort of modified date column in your source?

Comment: "Incremental Load" isn't some magic concept. There *must* be a way to identify new or modified rows. SSIS lookups, as the name says, do *lookups*, not INSERTs. If you try to force and INSERT or Ignore, you're doing it the slowest way possible, no matter what database is used. Even if you used MySQL and `ON CONFLICT IGNORE` you'd still get very very slow performance

Comment: All the major commercial databases (DB2, Oracle, SQL Server) have some kind of replication or change data capture that can be used to find and copy modified data. You'll have to find the equivalent for DB2. Another option is to use a modified date column or indicator and copy only columns that have been modified since the last time.   Another option is to copy all PK values to a staging table to identify which are new, then load data from DB2 only for the new PK values

Answer (score 0):

If your source is a SQL query from DB2 for instance, try adding a new column to this. It will be a checksum value over the columns you select "expect to change or want to monitor changes over".

```
SELECT 
BINARY_CHECKSUM(
    Column1
    ,Column2
    ,Column3)AS ChecksumValue
,Column1
,Column2
,Column3
FROM #TEMP
```

You would have to add this to your existing table in SQL as well to be able to start comparing.
If you have this, then you can do the lookup on the checksum value rater than on the columns. Since number lookups are a lot quicker than varchar comparisons over multiple columns. I am guessing since there is no key, you would then have to split the data between checksum matches (which should be no change existing records) and non matches. The non matches Could be new rows or just updates. But your set should be smaller to work with.

Good luck. HTH

Answer (score -1):

Look up is SSIS takes some time, so you can use ESQL Task and call the merge procedures.
I think what you can  do is use merge procedures there you can create a column in your source table and update the records in the column like

```
merge desination
using 
 {
 source columns from source s}
 join desination d
 on s.primarykey=d.primary key
when matched then
 s.updatedrecord=1
 when not matched then
 insert into desination columns.
```

from the above the query you new records will be inserted and the updated records with the help of updatedrecord column you can update or insert them in your destination table successfully.

you can go to the following link for  merge procedures.

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1042053-392-1.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: This is wrong on several levels. Fist, that's a lookup too. Second, the table is remote, where will `destination` come from? Where will the `updaterecord` come from and who's going to set it? Second, MERGE is not atomic and has a *lot* of bugs. If you only want to insert new rows, it's no better than an `INSERT ... SELECT  FROM ...`